# Multiply each element from an array with each element from a second array

Tags: c++, arrays

So we have to use functions to fill, multiply and print arrays.
So I created 3 functions: one to fill the arrays, one to print the arrays, and one to multiply the first 2 arrays between them. 
I have to use the print function 3 times: to print the initial 2 arrays and to print the array resulting from multiplication of the first 2 arrays. 
The problem I have is when I want to use "multiplication" function in order to multiply each element from the first array with every element from the second array.  I am doing something wrong with this function because when I try to launch it freezes.

It should work like this:
First array: 5, 5, 5;
Second array: 5, 10;
I should get this:
25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50;

This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void remplir(int array[], int dim); //function to fill array
void aficher(int array[], int dim); //function to print array
int multiplier(int array11[], int array22[], int dim1, int dim2, int   dim3); //function to multiply array


int main() {
int a1, a2, a3, array1[a1], array2[a2];
cout << "La dimension de la premiere table?" << endl;
cin >> a1;
while (a1 > 20) {
    cout << "La dimension maximum est 20! Reessayez!" << endl;
    cin >> a1;

}
remplir(array1, a1);
aficher(array1, a1);

cout << "La dimension de la deuxieme table?" << endl;
cin >> a2;
while (a2 > 20) {
    cout << "La dimension maximum est 20! Reessayez!" << endl;
    cin >> a2;

}
a3 = a1 * a2;
remplir(array2, a2);
aficher(array2, a2);

multiplier(array1, array2, a1, a2, a3);

return 0;

}

void remplir(int array[], int dim) {
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= dim - 1; i = i + 1) {
    cout << "Entrez la case numero " << i << endl;
    cin >> array[i];

}
}

void aficher(int array[], int dim) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= dim - 1; i = i + 1) {
    cout << "indice " << i << " = " << array[i] << endl;
}
}

int multiplier(int array11[], int array22[], int dim1, int dim2, int      dim3) {
int i = 0, a = 0, resultat[dim3];
for (i = 0; i <= dim1 - 1; i = i + 1) {
    for (i = 0; i <= dim2 - 1; i = i + 1) {

        resultat[i] = array11[a] * array22[i];

    }
    a = a + 1;
}

return resultat[i];

}
```

Comment: " I am doing something wrong" is not very clear explanation of your problem - exact compile/run-time error message or expected/observed behavior would be better.

Comment: If at all possible, use `std::array` (if you know the array size at compile time) or `std::vector` (if you don't) instead of built-in arrays. As it stands, your code really shouldn't even compile. Since it apparently does compile for you, I'm going to guess you're using `gcc` which has a bug ("extension", if you prefer) that allows this code to compile (but not work).

Comment: I am new to C++, this is actually the first code we are learning. The point of this exercise is to show us how to use functions to do different things like: multiply arrays, fill arrays, print values from arrays.
So I don't really understand why I should use "std::vector" and how...

Answer (score 2):

Despite your question not actually explaining what kind of problem you're having, I can already see a big mistake. This line:

`int a1 = 0, a2 = 0, a3 = 0, array1[a1], array2[a2], array3[a3];`

You've created three zero-sized arrays. And no matter what you do with the a1, a2, a3 variables afterwards, those arrays will continue to remain the same size. Raw arrays do not dynamically resize in C++.

So anything else you're doing trying to index into those arrays is running off into other memory and undoubtedly giving weird results and causing trouble.

Comment: you mentioned it before I got to it! :)

Comment: I am getting false results. If I fill the first array with vaules: 5, 5, 5; and the second array with value:5; I should get this result:
25, 25, 25.
Instead I get some random numbers...

Comment: Yes. Going past the ends of arrays can end up with incorrect and "random" results. Unlike some languages, C++ doesn't stop you from doing that. It expects you the developer to ensure the logic is correct.